# Sending mails via Mutt and Gmail: Duplicates

Tags: mutt

I'm trying to set up Mutt with GMail for the first time. It seems to work pretty well. However, when I send a mail from Mutt, it appears twice in GMail's *Sent* folder. (I assume it's also sent twice - I'm trying to validate that.)

My configuration (Stripped of coloring):

```
# A basic .muttrc for use with Gmail
# Change the following six lines to match your Gmail account details
set imap_user = "XX"
set smtp_url = "XX@gmail.com@smtp.gmail.com:587/"
set from = "XX"
set realname = "XX"

# Change the following line to a different editor you prefer.
set editor = "vim"

# Basic config, you can leave this as is
set folder = "imaps://imap.gmail.com:993"
set spoolfile = "+INBOX"
set imap_check_subscribed
set hostname = gmail.com
set mail_check = 120
set timeout = 300
set imap_keepalive = 300
set postponed = "+[Gmail]/Drafts"
set record = "+[Gmail]/Sent Mail"
set header_cache=~/.mutt/cache/headers
set message_cachedir=~/.mutt/cache/bodies
set certificate_file=~/.mutt/certificates
set move = no
set include
set sort = 'threads'
set sort_aux = 'reverse-last-date-received'
set auto_tag = yes
hdr_order Date From To Cc
auto_view text/html
bind editor <Tab> complete-query
bind editor ^T complete
bind editor <space> noop

# Gmail-style keyboard shortcuts
macro index,pager y "<enter-command>unset trash\n <delete-message>" "Gmail archive message"
macro index,pager d "<enter-command>set trash=\"imaps://imap.googlemail.com/[Gmail]/Bin\"\n <delete-message>" "Gmail delete message"
macro index,pager gl "<change-folder>"
macro index,pager gi "<change-folder>=INBOX<enter>" "Go to inbox"
macro index,pager ga "<change-folder>=[Gmail]/All Mail<enter>" "Go to all mail"
macro index,pager gs "<change-folder>=[Gmail]/Starred<enter>" "Go to starred messages"
macro index,pager gd "<change-folder>=[Gmail]/Drafts<enter>" "Go to drafts"
macro index,pager gt "<change-folder>=[Gmail]/Sent Mail<enter>" "Go to sent mail"

#Don't prompt on exit
set quit=yes


## =================
#Color definitions
## =================

set pgp_autosign
```

Comment: `macro index,pager d "<enter-command>set trash=\"=[Gmail]/Bin\"\n <delete-message>" "Gmail delete message"`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To get rid of duplicates, unset `$record`. Gmail's SMTP server stores the message automatically.

Answer (score 8):

Don't save sent messages, Gmail has that function inbuilt, `set record = "+[Gmail]/Sent Mail"` is unnecessary (and causes the issue you describe).

Answer (score 7):

The Gmail server automatically stores a copy of all sent mail for you, so you do not need mutt to also store a copy.  You want to keep the `$record` setting as that allows you to view the sent folder from mutt via the `<` shortcut.  What you want to do is to set `$copy` to `no` to disable mutt's storing of all sent mail:

```
set record = "+[Gmail]/Sent Mail"
set copy = no
```

And no, the emails were not actually sent to the recipients twice.

Comment: Upvoted for the useful tip about using `<` (which I didn’t know about). This is also the only answer that re-assures the OP about mails not being sent twice.

Answer (score 4):

Via: http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=78892

> Do NOT save sent messages on the server. If your client is sending mail through Gmail's SMTP server, your sent messages will be automatically copied to the [Gmail]/Sent Mail folder.