# Configuring mutt for Office365 - displaying threads and sent mail correctly

Tags: email, office365, mutt

I'm trying to set up mutt to use it with my business email that is hosted by Office365. I used a muttrc i found on github for my initial configuration and changed it a bit according to my needs and ended up with this:

```
source "~/.mutt/user"

# IMAP config
set imap_user="$my_username@$my_domain"

set folder="imaps://outlook.office365.com/"
set spoolfile= +INBOX
set postponed= +$my_drafts_noquote
set record = +$my_sent_noquote
set trash = +$my_trash_noquote
mailboxes

set imap_check_subscribed="yes"
set imap_list_subscribed="yes"
set timeout=15
set mail_check=90
set imap_keepalive=180
set imap_idle
unset mark_old
set ssl_use_sslv3=yes

# SMTP config
set realname = $my_realname
set from = "$my_username@$my_domain"
set hostname = $my_domain
set smtp_url = "smtp://$my_username@$my_domain@outlook.office365.com:587/"
set ssl_force_tls = yes
set smtp_authenticators = "login"

set editor = "vim"

set mailcap_path = ~/.mutt/mailcap

auto_view text/html
alternative_order text/html text/plain text/enriched

auto_view text/calendar application/ics
auto_view applica/pdf

set sort=threads
set sort_browser=date
set sort_aux=reverse-last-date-received

source ~/.mutt/contacts.list
```

The problem I'm having is with the sent mail. The sent mail is displayed correctly in mutt, but when I open it in Outlook, all sent messages are duplicated (not sent twice, but displayed twice in Outlook). I looked around and found an [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/224524/sending-mails-via-mutt-and-gmail-duplicates/224548) that said to try unsetting record or the copy flag. This resolved the problem in Outlook (messages weren't duplicated anymore), but now mutt wasn't displaying the sent messages properly. Sent folder is empty and when, for instance, replying to an email, the sent email is not displayed. My question is whether it's possible to get both? So I want mutt to display the sent mail properly in the INBOX folder in threads and, when I open it in Outlook there are no duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the `record` to `+INBOX` did the trick.

---

[Source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/209101/189970)
Original answer (at the time of writing this one):

I found a solution that works for me even though it is not pretty.

```
set record = "+INBOX"
```

I just set record to my inbox, in that way the messages get threaded. It might not be ideal when I am the first sending an e-mail, but normally I will get an answer, so no issue.